# In TFS can I move folder from one project to another without getting latest

Tags: tfs

I am cleaning up TFS which has multiple projects and multiple folders within. I want to move folder from one project to another. The 'Move' option in the right click menu is disabled until I get the source code. I want to know if there is a way to move it without getting latest. I want to avoid the 'getting latest' activity since that is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to pull the files local first.